# Using .closest and .find to get values to manipulate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello and thank you in advance.

Am I in the right direction with using `.closest` and `.find` to find the values from `.cab` input field?

I plan to take those values and then display a proper door size in the .cdmyour DIV.

Would there be a better way of completing this? This will be one row of about 20, so I'd rather not use ID's to get the job done since I believe this would require more than necessary code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cab").keyup(function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.cdmrow');
    var width = parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(0)").val();
    var height = parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(1)").val();
    var dwidth = parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(2)").val();
    var dheight = parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(3)").val();
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
    console.log(dwidth);
    console.log(dheight);
  })
})
```

```css
.cdmh1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.cdmrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
}

.cdmcol {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 14.28%;
}

.cdmcol1 {
  width: 14.28%;
}

.cdmcolmeas {
  width: 57.14%;
}

.cdmyourord {
  width: 28.58%;
}

.cdmcolhalf {
  width: 7.142%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: .5px;
}

.cdmyour {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.cab {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="cdmh1">
    About Your Space | Cabinet Door Measurements
  </h1>
  <div class="cdmtable">
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol1">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolmeas">
        Your Cabinet's Measurements
      </div>
      <div class="cdmyourord cdmyour">
        Your Order
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol cdmyour">
        Single Doors
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol cdmyour">
        Double Doors
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Opening Width (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Opening Height (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Reveal Between Double Doors (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Desired Overlay (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Width (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Height (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Width (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Height (in)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Door 1
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying it out and seeing if it works seems like a logical next step.

Comment: Very common pattern  using closest and find like you are

Comment: Unrelated: instead of `keyup` event use `input` as that also responds when keeping key pressed (repeating a char), and when using mouse or context menu to edit content (think of drag, copy/paste).

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Side note; rather than performing repeated finds on the parent for each cdmcolhalf, you could get them all, put them in a variable, and then to get each one do `eq(#)` off of it.  It would save you 3 dom selections.

Comment: Probably a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you are asking how to improve code.

Comment: I've tried to console.log my variables (width, height, etc) but It doesn't appear to capture the input values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close you could attach the retrieved values to the related columns using `.text()`.

**Shorter version :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cab").on('input', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.cdmrow');

    parent.find(".cab").each(function(i, v) {
      parent.find(".cdmcolhalf").eq(i).text($(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** You've to change the selector class from `cdmcolhalf` to `cab` and I suggest the use of `input` event instead since it's more efficient when tracking the user inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cab").on('input', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.cdmrow');

    var width = parent.find(".cab:eq(0)").val();
    var height = parent.find(".cab:eq(1)").val();
    var dwidth = parent.find(".cab:eq(2)").val();
    var dheight = parent.find(".cab:eq(3)").val();

    parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(0)").text(width);
    parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(1)").text(height);
    parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(2)").text(dwidth);
    parent.find(".cdmcolhalf:eq(3)").text(dheight);
  })
})
```

```css
.cdmh1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.cdmrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
}

.cdmcol {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 14.28%;
}

.cdmcol1 {
  width: 14.28%;
}

.cdmcolmeas {
  width: 57.14%;
}

.cdmyourord {
  width: 28.58%;
}

.cdmcolhalf {
  width: 7.142%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: .5px;
}

.cdmyour {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.cab {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h1 class="cdmh1">
    About Your Space | Cabinet Door Measurements
  </h1>
  <div class="cdmtable">
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol1">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolmeas">
        Your Cabinet's Measurements
      </div>
      <div class="cdmyourord cdmyour">
        Your Order
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol cdmyour">
        Single Doors
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol cdmyour">
        Double Doors
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Opening Width (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Opening Height (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Reveal Between Double Doors (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Desired Overlay (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Width (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Height (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Width (in)
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
        Height (in)
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Door 1
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cdmrow">
      <div class="cdmcol">
        Door 2
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcol">
        <input class="cab" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
      <div class="cdmcolhalf cdmyour">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked this suggestion carlos?

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! Very glad to see I was on the right track.

Comment: Yes you was, you're welcome glad I could help. HAPPY CODING